# отступы в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

При добавлении кнопки в строчку с лейблами увеличиваются отступы.
Если убрать кнопку `btn`, то отступы уменьшатся.

С кнопкой:
[image: с кнопкой]
Без кнопки:
[image: без кнопки]

Как это исправить?

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
def size(w,h,qframe):
    qframe.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    ws = qframe.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = qframe.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    qframe.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

root = ThemedTk()
root.title('DB')
root.set_theme("breeze")
w = 850
h = 600
size(w,h,root)
main = Frame(root)
main.grid()
boldStyle = ttk.Style ()
boldStyle.configure("Bold.TButton", font = ('Arial','14'))

num    = ttk.Label(main,text='fdsfdsfsf',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=12,anchor='w').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W,pady=(5,0),padx=2)
type   = ttk.Label(main,text='sadasdasd',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=10).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W,pady=(5,0))
cab    = ttk.Label(main,text='dsasdasda',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=7,anchor='w').grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W,pady=(5,0),padx=2)
status = ttk.Label(main,text='dasdasdsa',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=7).grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=W,pady=(5,0))
data   = ttk.Label(main,text='dasdsadas',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=14).grid(row=1,column=5,sticky=W,pady=(5,0),padx=(2,0))
btn    = ttk.Button(main,text='fdsfsdfs',style = 'Bold.TButton',width=11).grid(row=1,column=6,sticky=W,pady=(10,0),padx=(2,0))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте кнопке такой же вертикальный отступ (`pady`) как у других виджетов в строке (`(5,0)` вместо `(10,0)`), тогда не будет увеличиваться:

```
btn = ttk.Button(main,text='fdsfsdfs',style = 'Bold.TButton',width=11)
btn.grid(row=1,column=6,sticky=W,pady=(5,0),padx=(2,0))
```

Если проблема в том, что `Button` получается выше чем `Label`-ы, то можно в параметр `sticky` добавить `NS`, чтобы `Label`-ы расширялись под максимальную высоту строки сетки (ну и `pady` тоже сделать везде одинаковым, иначе кнопка по высоте будет ниже, чем метки):

```
num    = ttk.Label(main,text='fdsfdsfsf',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=12,anchor='w').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W+NS,pady=(5,0),padx=2)
type   = ttk.Label(main,text='sadasdasd',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=10).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W+NS,pady=(5,0))
cab    = ttk.Label(main,text='dsasdasda',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=7,anchor='w').grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W+NS,pady=(5,0),padx=2)
status = ttk.Label(main,text='dasdasdsa',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=7).grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=W+NS,pady=(5,0))
data   = ttk.Label(main,text='dasdsadas',font='Arial 16',background='#b3b4bc',width=14).grid(row=1,column=5,sticky=W+NS,pady=(5,0),padx=(2,0))
btn    = ttk.Button(main,text='fdsfsdfs',style = 'Bold.TButton',width=11).grid(row=1,column=6,sticky=W+NS,pady=(5,0),padx=(2,0))
```

`sticky=W+NS` можно заменить на `sticky='wns'`

Кстати, лучше разделять запись виджетов в переменную и их размещение с помощью `grid`/`pack`/`place`: сейчас у вас в переменные записывается не виджет, а то что возвращает метод `grid` - а это всегда `None`.

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался сам.
Так как кнопка по ширине больше, чем лейбл, она ставит свою ширину для строчки.
Поэтому можно кнопке дать 2 строчки с помощью **rowspan**
`btn.grid(row=1,rowspan=2,column=6,sticky=W,pady=(5,0),padx=(2,0))`